# sending data to mysql creates table but nothing is stored in the table

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I have a simple webapp that show your location in (lat, lon) 
however I want that lat and lon saved to mySql.

```
    function callback(position) {
   document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
   document.getElementById('lon').innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;}
```

is what I am using to see the latitude and longitude.

the code i am using to send the information is

```
<?php
$sql="INSERT INTO poi_example (lat, lon)
VALUES
('$_POST[lat]','$_POST[lon]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$dbcnx))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error($dbcnx));
  }
mysql_close($dbcnx);

?>
```

however when the page loads a blank lat and lon is inputed in mySql.

I am assuming it is due to the time it take the google api to get location vs the time it creates and inserts. is there away i can put a delay on the insert??

Comment: How are you moving to the page with the PHP script? If you are using a form make sure the method='post'. If you are simply using the url to store values (e.g. http://example.com/location?lat=111&lon=222) then use $_GET instead of $_POST

Comment: I am not using a form. just when i go to the page it sends my location to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you aren't using a `<form>`, I suggest the following code to send the value using Javascript and retrieve it using PHP.

First you will grab the variable as you are send them to a PHP script:

```
function(){
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lon = position.coords.longitude;
  window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com/store.php?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon;
}
```

Now that you have the values in the URL bar you can use the `$_GET` method to grab them and store them into the database:

**store.php**

```
<?php

  $sql="INSERT INTO poi_example (lat, lon)
  VALUES
  ('".$_GET["lat"]."','".$_GET["lon"]."')";

  if (!mysql_query($sql,$dbcnx))
  {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($dbcnx));
  }
  mysql_close($dbcnx);

?>
```

I assumed that you have the credentials to connect to the SQL database.

Comment: Thanks Ill try it.. and yes I can connect to SQL! thanks again